# How to add a custom action button to the wagtail admin changelist pages?

Tags: django, wagtail

I want to achieve this feature for models that registered via modeladmin module.

Comment: After reading Loïc's answer carefully, it is great when you are dealing with wagtail pages and it works just fine. But if you want to add custom buttons to the model admin panels you should follow the instructions described in this link: [http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/modeladmin/primer.html?highlight=button_helper_class#modeladmin-button-helper-class](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/modeladmin/primer.html?highlight=button_helper_class#modeladmin-button-helper-class)

Comment: Hi @Bhargav! Can I ask why did you delete my answer? Doesn't It answer the question?

Comment: Firstly, I wanted to convert it to a comment and instead converted into an edit, sorry for that. Secondly, it was just a link only answer. [It would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer on the site, and provide the link for reference. Once you edit it, let me know and I'll undelete it for you.

Comment: Ok thanks for your response. I will add the sample code as soon as I can.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the [`register_page_listing_buttons`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1/reference/hooks.html?highlight=hooks#register-page-listing-buttons) or [`register_page_listing_more_buttons`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1/reference/hooks.html?highlight=hooks#register-page-listing-more-buttons) hooks.

Example from the documentation:

```
from wagtail.admin import widgets as wagtailadmin_widgets

@hooks.register('register_page_listing_buttons')
def page_listing_buttons(page, page_perms, is_parent=False):
    yield wagtailadmin_widgets.PageListingButton(
        'A page listing button',
        '/goes/to/a/url/',
        priority=10
    )
```